# Update Markers on Location Change Google Map v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker, currentlocation

I want to update All Markers Text i.e. **Marker with Red Circle** in Image on Location Change. I tried the Idea of `Removing all Previous Markers & adding all of them again with Updated Text`.But Doing So gives me Error Of :::: **Out Of Memory Exception** And I also tried To Update Only Text of All Markers But it is not updating.
[image: Markers like Red Circle to be Updated on location Change]

Here is my **Xml File** For Custom Layout Of Marker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeTapMarker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tapmarker" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTapMarkerDist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white_selector"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is My Code File in which i am upadting text on Location Change.

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        data(intent);
    }
};

private void data(Intent intent)
{
    Log.e("BROADCAST RECIEVER CALLED","///////////////////// BROADCAST RECIEVER     CALLED ////////////////////////");
    Location location = (Location) intent.getParcelableExtra("location");

    if(location != null)
    {
                txtTapMarkerDist.setText(new  DecimalFormat("###").format(getDistance(curr_lat, curr_long, tapmarkerlat,tapmarkerlong)));
            }

    }
```

I am registering This Reciever as below.

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));
```

I am getting Location Perfectly So **BroadcastReceiver** Code is Working Perfectly. And Also **Single marker** the Marker in blue is updating the Text With Location. But the Problem is with **Updating Multiple Marker's Text With Location Change**...
Any One Please Help me Out of This Problem.Any help is Appreciated.